# SFDX: Trying to source push omniscript files gives File or folder not found error

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, omnistudio, health-cloud, omniscript

When I source push omniscript files for the first time to my scratch org, the deploy succeeds. If I make some changes to the file and push it again  to same scratch org. I always end up in getting FILE NOT FOLDER not found error

I am using

```
sf project deploy start --metadata OmniScript --target-org OmniProject
```

I tried other approaches too, but it is the same issue